# UIButton with target:self not being sent to self?

Tags: ios, uibutton, action, targets

I'm creating a new UIViewController (call it MyViewController), and adding the view (MyView) as a subview of a TableViewCell.  Within MyView , there's a button.  That button is created programmatically during MyViewController's init, as such:

```
-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
        [self.view setFrame:frame];

        _yesButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame.size.width-150, 40, 140, 30)];
        [_yesButton setTitle:@"Yeah!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        [_yesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        [self.view addSubview:_yesButton];
    }
    return self;
}
```

Now, seems straightforward.  It displays properly, everything looks great in the simulator.

But when I click on the "_yesButton" within MyView, I get a crash with this error:

```
-[_UITableViewCellSeparatorView didClick]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x7b7f7ec0
```

What?  When did "_UITableViewCellSeparatorView" come into the equation?  I specifically told the _yesButton to set the Target to "self", so the selector should be sent to MyViewController, right?  I could even imagine it getting tripped up and sending it to the UITableViewCell, since MyView is embedded within a TableViewCell, but why a SeperatorView?

Can anyone tell me how to get my _yesButton to send the call back to the MyViewController that it's being created within?  And for bonus points, can you explain how "_UITableViewCellSeparatorView" became a thing in this conversation at all?

**Edit:** Here's how I'm building the cell in the TableView, and adding MyView to it.  Note that I'm deliberately not using dequeuing for this row, although that might change if it's the source of the problem.

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"MyViewCell"];

MyViewController *myViewController = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithFrame:cell.contentView.frame];
[cell.contentView addSubview:myViewController.view];

return cell;
```

And the didClick method is currently empty, (it never even gets there, so I haven't gotten that far in writing it), but it's currently defined within MyViewController simply as:

```
-(void)didClick {

}
```

Comment: How are you adding this `MyViewController` view to the cell?  Can you show the definition of the `didClick` method?

Comment: `UIViewController` does not declares `initWithFrame` method. Are you sure that code snippet is not inside `UITableViewCellSeparatorView`?

Comment: @Paulw11 Edited with the code you requested.

Comment: @ssantos I wrote an `initWithFrame` method for my `MyViewController` subclass of `UIViewController`.

Comment: One more question - how is _yesButton declared?

Comment: Yeah, the `initWithFrame` is getting called and working perfectly.  MyViewController is created, the view gets added to the TableViewCell, appears successfully in the cell when I run the app, etc.  It's just tapping on the button that causes a problem.  And @Paulw11 - it's just a simple `@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *yesButton;` in the H file of MyViewController.

Comment: Ok. I thought it might be `weak` or something because what you have has the hallmarks of a pointer being messed up and pointing to an incorrect object.  Have you tried using `self.yesButton` instead of accessing the iVar directly?

Comment: @Paulw11 Gotcha.  :)  And no I hadn't, but I just tried switching all the "_yesButton"s to "self.yesButton"s and the crash still happened.

Comment: Have you considered just using a straight-forward custom cell object?

Comment: Do you really need that the action being fired in `MyViewController` ? And not in your `UITableViewController`

Comment: Actually this is because you `MyViewController` is not retain by ARC. The `dealloc` method id being called. Figure out another way to do it. As @Paulw11 said you should implement a custom `UITableViewCell`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Solution #1**

Actually this is because you `MyViewController` is not retain by ARC. The `dealloc` method id being called. Add ans instance of your controller in your `UITableViewController` will fix the issue and make ARC retains your controller.

**Solution #2**

Try something like this.

Create a custom `UITableViewCell` :

MyCustomCell.h :

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface MyCustomCell : UITableViewCell

@property (strong, nonatomic) UIButton *yesButton;

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame;

@end
```

MyCustomCell.m :

```
#import "MyCustomCell.h"

@implementation MyCustomCell

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

-(id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super init];
    if(self) {
       [self.view setFrame:frame];

       _yesButton = [[UIButton alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(frame)];
       [_yesButton setTitle:@"Yeah!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
       [self.contentView addSubview:_yesButton];
    }
    return self;
}
@end
```

In your `UITableViewController`in the `viewDidLoad` function :

```
[self.tableView registerClass:[MyCustomCell class] forCellReuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
```

Then in your `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:`

```
MyCustomCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifierr forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell == nil) {
     cell = [[MyCustomCell alloc] initWithFrame:frame];
     [cell.yesButton addTarget:self action:@selector(didClick) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
}
```

And now implement the following in your `UITableViewController`:

```
-(void)didClick {
   // The following identify the in which cell the action has been triggered
   NSSet *touches = [event allTouches];
   UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];
   CGPoint currentTouchPosition = [touch locationInView:self.tableView];
   NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint: currentTouchPosition];
   if (indexPath != nil)
   {
    // Do whatever you want for the given cell
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this view can't be a custom cell.  It's a view that's used in several places in my app, sometimes embedded in cells, sometimes elsewhere.  That being said, your comment about it not being retained in ARC was the solution!  I just created an instance variable in my TableViewController, added THAT to the cell, and everything works perfectly.  :)  Put that info into your answer, and I'll accept it.  Thanks!

Comment: I edited my answer to solve your problem as you told me. I let the other solution for people who would like to do something similar with a custom cell.

Answer (score 0):

I think that you're adopting a wrong approach.

The view cells are not living in memory like views. We may say that once the drawing done, it does not exists anymore.

For all cells operations, you should set you TableViewController as target, and handle the click method in this controller.
Only this controller has a global knowledge of the data in the cells and the cells formats.

You can set the tag of the button to the row index to know what row has been clicked.

your didClick selector is also not correct. It should have this form

```
-(void)didClick:(id)sender
{
    NSInteger clickedRow = ((UIButton*)sender).tag
}
```

And so be connected like this:

```
[_yesButton addTarget:<YourTableController> action:@selector(didClick:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
```

Comment: About your separator cell getting the message, it is because of the volatility  of cells… Your log gives this now, but I guess it may give another result in another context. That's common for memory errors - they give mysterious results.

Reusable Cells stay alive in memory - The default separator is probably one of them. Just a guess… :/

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this view can't have its logic tied to the TableViewController. It's a view that's used in several places in my app, sometimes embedded in cells, sometimes elsewhere.  (Think of it like an infobox.)  I needed the View to be self-contained, so it can be added as a subview anywhere it needed to go.  In this case, embedding it in the TableViewCell caused a problem, but tying the logic to the TableViewController wasn't a viable solution.  Thanks anyway!

Comment: Ok… I hope you found the right way so.

I've been in the same case on some of my apps. What I've did is a TableViewController subclass that handles all my app specific clicks in cells. Maybe that was not the right way.

Thanks for your acknowledgement. ; )

Answer (score -1):

The problem is that the instance you thing to be kind of `MyViewController`, it is no. It is instead `UITableViewCellSeparatorView`.

The biggest error, is that **you are trying to init a view controller by a method which is not supported from the class `UIViewController`**, but is instead part of `UIView`:

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
```

I suggest you to review it before going ahead.

Comment: Yeah, I already said in the comments that `initWithFrame` is a method I wrote for this class.  Also, I said in the question that the view loaded and displayed properly, which wouldn't have happened if I tried to init it with a non-existant method.  Strongly suggest you review the question before answering.  ;)

Comment: Sorry, I thought was really out of any mind in the world writing a custom method named `initWithFrame:`, exactly like the method of `UIView`. You know, you can't initialising a `UIViewController` **with a frame** right? So this is totally wrong from any point of view. It is strongly suggested to learn a bit more of "how to write clean, scalable, maintainable, understandable and that makes sense code". I understand your sarcasm but maybe you could spend time to reflect and understand your errors rather than doing this. Good luck!

Comment: ViewControllers don't have frames, but they have Views and Views have frames.  I found it convenient to pass in the needed frame at the moment that the controller was initialized, and set the view to that frame in the same step.  And, as I said in my question, it worked perfectly.  Just because YOU don't understand my thought process (likely because, as has been established, you *didn't even read the question*), doesn't mean my code isn't understandable.  I'd appreciate it if you'd stop making condescending comments about how I don't know what I'm doing.

Comment: Wow, man.  You downvoted my question, because you didn't understand it?  Real mature.

Comment: Yes MAN, you know, I thought you was wrongly doing that, instead you are doing this knowledgeably, and you don't leave me other choice. See you MAN and again good luck.